# Re-factor simple SQL statement with WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I feel there must be a more efficient way to do this. I want to allow the caller to either pull ALL books, or books that are not hidden (see below)

```
if isnull(@ShowHiddenBooks, 0) = 1
    begin
        select
            (long list of fields)
        from
            MyTable
        where
            MyField = @SomeField
    end
else
    begin
        select
            (long list of fields)
        from
            MyTable
        where
            MyField = @SomeField and
            IsHidden = 0    
    end
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
Select *
from MyTable
where MyField = @SomeField and
(isHidden = 0 or @showHiddenBooks = 1)
```

Comment: This fails ti take into account when @showHiddenBooks is null.

Comment: @Steve, if it's null, it won't be 1

Comment: @ps2goat the semantics of SQL are different than C#,  null = 1 is true

Comment: Firstly I thought as Steve but then I realize that this is correct. + from me.

Comment: @Steve no it isn't.  Run this statement: `select case when null = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end`  You'll see the result is 'false'

Comment: @Steve, you are wrong, null = 1 is not true, it is unknown! Even more, null = null is unknown!

Comment: In response to comments, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca660/2/0.  Changing the declared value of @showHiddenBooks from NULL to 0 has no impact on the results.  That said, adding IsNull to the query would do no harm, it would just be redundant.

Comment: @Steve, there is an option to treat null as 0 in sql server, but I've never seen it treated equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivqlent to:

```
 select (long list of fields)
    from
        MyTable
    where
        MyField = @SomeField and
        (IsHidden = 0 or isnull(@ShowHiddenBooks, 0) = 1)
```